# Send a dictionary through HTML form to Django

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, forms

I have a form in HTML where I have an input called "csvModified", this is initialized with an empty value and I give it the following data.

```
    <input type="hidden" name="csvModified" id="csvModified" value="" />
    ...
    var dict_separators = {};
    dict_separators["column"] = separator_columns;  (String)
    dict_separators["thousand"] = separator_thousands;  (String)
    dict_separators["decimal"] = separator_decimals;  (String)
    dict_separators["children"] = final_data;  (Array [Strings])
    ...
    document.getElementById('csvModified').value = dict_separators;
```

on Django I am recieving this as

```
data = request.POST.get('csvModified')
print(data)
```

However the output is the following [object Object]

Am I sending the data correctly from the HTML Form? Is the problem in Python? How can I get the data and iterate over it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to serialize the javascript object before posting it with your form:

```js
document.getElementById('csvModified').value = JSON.stringify(dict_separators);
```

`[object Object]` is just the default string representation of a javascript object.

You'll need to use json.loads() on the python end to convert it into a dict.

Comment: Thank you it worked perfectly! I knew I had to do something with JSON, but what I had done didn't work.